# jQuery validation and AJAX twice loaded form

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

here's a simple scenario

1) I'm navigation through my site pages by using AJAX. Just for UI better appearance (animations etc.)

2) if user is not authenticated, I load via AJAX the login form.
That form contains the following simple code

```
$('#ajaxform').validate(
{
   rules: {
      login: {
         minlength: 2,
         required: true
      },
      password: {
         required: true,
         minlength: 2
      }
   },
   highlight: function (element) {
      $(element).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
   },
   success: function (element) {
      element.addClass('valid').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
      $('label.valid.success').remove();
   }
});
```

3) and here's the thing - if user instead of filling in that form and authenticating himself, and again clicks on any element which again loads via AJAX that login form, `the validation is not working anymore`.

Why ?

I've tried to use `$("#ajaxform").unbind('validate');` and then  `$('#ajaxform').validate(...);` but without success.

Comment: could we get the code for your page and the rest of the ajax calls?

Comment: Tried adding `.removeClass('valid')` to the `highlight` function?

Comment: what do you mean by the validation is not working anymore? you said that the form loads again.

Comment: by 'not working' I mean the validation does not fire.

Comment: Why not include it in an external JS and have it always listening for the event in your `ready()`. That way, you don't have to bind and unbind it all the time...

Comment: but if I move out that code as-is to the externat file, the validation will not work even if the login form is loaded for the first time

Answer (score 1):

the problem is `.validate()` should only be called once on DOM to initialize the things you want, and in your case it's being called again for an already initialized thing, my suggestion  is a hack not a solution to the problem since there might be better ones, but you may like it, when you show the from, disable the rest of the page when you show the login layer to prevent the user from clicking anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've figured it out. My login form has had the `id='myForm` attribute. I've replaced it with `class='myForm` and anso changed the validation code to

```
$('form.myForm').last().validate(
        {
            rules: {
                login: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function (element) {
                element.addClass('valid').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                $('label.valid.success').remove();
            }
        });
```

now it's working, but in my opinion it is not the best approach (but sometimes the end justifies the means)